# How to change NestJS Decorator string parameter when importing library

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs, monorepo, typescript-decorator

I have a NestJs monorepo with some Apps (microservices) and Libs.
I have a Service class that I use in all my apps, so I wanted to extract it in a lib.

I thought it's good idea, but then I realized, I have a decorator on a method of this class, that needs a **different const string** for every app.
Seems I'm not able to achieve that... Is there any way?
Basically I would need to "inject" a const string from the loading app into the lib to be used by the decorator.

To be more specific, the decorator is a `@RabbitSubscribe()` (from `golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq`), and the queue name (const string parameter for the decorator) needs to be different for each module.

But more generically, if I have this class in a lib:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  @ADecorator({
    param: 'this is the string',
  })
  myFunction() { ... }
}
```

How can I import it in different Apps, with a different string param for each app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq.`

The official configuration module for NestJS can only be instantiated once the DI system for NestJS is bootstrapped. For this reason, it's impossible to dynamically configure a decorator using this module.

To work around this issue (and a few others including better type saftey) I built an [alternative configuration package](https://github.com/golevelup/ts-ecosystem/blob/master/libs/profiguration/README.md) that works with ENV and .env files to help you configure your app(s). Using this package it's possible to bootstrap your app configuration *before* NestJS DI and any files including Decorators are imported so you could write code like:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  @ADecorator({
    param: config.queueName,
  })
  myFunction() { ... }
}
```

Where `config.queueName` could be retrieved differently in each app instance based on an ENV value or loaded from a .env or .json file

Comment: I see, thanks for confirming it's not possible. I will give a try to your "profiguration" if I get the time.